# What can cause disagreements in Marketing Cloud between Send email and Update records?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, campaign

We have this scenario: we've sent 1818 emails to a 1818 campaign members... but, only 1516 are updated in the next action. The second action only has a few updated fields with normal values:

[image]

Do you know why we can have this disagreement...? thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have duplicates in the email activity?

Comment: No... I solved the mistery! some people were in a Suppression List and MC fails in sending the Email (I can see in the View Event Results and the in the Journey History for a concrete Contact Key.

Comment: So, if the Step of sending an email fails, then, MC doesn't execute the Next one, and then, this step has less people quantity. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the mistery! some people were in a Suppression List and MC fails in sending the Email (I can see in the **View Event Results** and the in the **Journey History** for a concrete Contact Key).

So, if the Step of sending an email fails, then, MC doesn't execute the Next one, and then, this step has less people quantity. :)

[image]